# Raspberry Pi starts lightdm, then goes to black screen with cursor and pulsing monitor backlight

Tags: raspbian, boot, xorg

I used rpi-update to update Raspbian, then restarted it. It got through the boot screen, but then just showed a black screen with a flashing cursor. For some reason, the monitor's backlight was pulsing every second or so as well. The LEDs were all on on the board except for the OK LED.

I reinstalled raspbian with Win32DiskImager, but the same thing is still happening.

The last messages shown before the screen goes blank are:
`Starting dphys-swapfile swapfile setup ...

want /var/swap=100MByte, checking existing: keeping it

done.

[ ok ] Starting Light Display Manager: lightdm`

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Could you clarify exactly how far it got? Kernel loading? Start of init? Services launched by init?

Comment: I've updated the question with the stage it's at before going blank. I'm not too familiar with Linux or the RPI, so please let me know if it's not enough information.

Comment: It could be switching to a resolution that your monitor does not support.

Comment: Make sure it's not a powersupply problem. Try turning up the `config_hdmi_boost` in `/boot/config.txt`

Comment: Your monitor does not support that resolution. Maybe rpi-update changed some config files that related to X session. What happen when you press CTRL-ALT-Fx (x = 1...6) ? Do you get TTY login?

Comment: CTRL-ALT-F1 lets me login using the default login details, then when I enter 'startx' as it suggests, it says 'waiting for X server to begin accepting connections', then endlessly repeats 'No protocol specified'.

Comment: What does `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` show? Any errors? Any warnings about unsupported resolutions or the like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some googling revealed that the problem was that the partition was full, so increasing it with gparted seems to have fixed it.